Upgrade from 22.04 to 24.04.1 did not complete
I tried to upgrade yesterday from Ubuntu 22.04 to 24.04.1. It appeared to be going fine, when the screen when blank and I got a blinking cursor. Now Ubuntu does not boot. When I start it up, it appears to be Ubuntu 22.04.
I tried a sudo apt update
and I get
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/noble/InRelease Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
and several other similar messages
sudo apt upgrade
lists a whole lot of unmet dependencies and 'Try apt --fix-broken install'
sudo apt --fix-broken install
gives
Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages
Unable to correct dependencies
There are no held packages.
How do I resolve this?

This question is similar to: E:Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Try this:
Open a terminal.
Run in it:
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt -f install
sudo apt update
sudo apt dist-upgrade


I tried what you suggested:
sudo dpkg --configure -a
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cups-ipp-utils:
cups-ipp-utils depends on libcups2t64 (= 2.4.7-1.2ubuntu7.2); however:
Package libcups2t64 is not installed.
And so on for the rest of the packages with dependency problems.
sudo apt -f install
also reports dependency problems.

If a particular package won't update, you can try removing it. For instance CUPS is printing support: remove it, and while you won't be able to print, you can possibly complete the update, then when it's working again, reinstall CUPS. If that sounds worth a go, try sudo apt remove cups-ipp-utils and then try the commands given above again.
